# Using RDBMS data to fuel SoapUI or similar testing tool

Tags: web-services, testing, soap, soapui

Does anyone have experience using DB data to fuel any variant of SOAP load testing tool?  I have data in a DB that I can use to build my SOAP string and I have to build a few thousand independent test transactions to throw at the web service.

Has anyone done this?  If so what tool did you use?  Any tips for pulling this off would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve got quite a few options here.

In short, you can use the contents of your db to populate the requests.  SoapUi has an ODBC test steps which allows you to connect to a db, run a query and process the results.

If this test step doesn’t offer the flexibility you need, you can use a Groovy test step to script how you want to interact with the db.

Lastly, the approach you describe to run 1000’s of request using your data to populate the requests is a ‘data driven test’.

The Smartbear sites has loads of examples on how to set these up.  The Smartbear site and SO forums has lots of questions on this topic too.

Comment: Unfortunately, data driven testing is only available in Pro and I'm on the Open Source version.

Comment: True, the smart out of the box stuff is pro version only, but if you look for data driven on SoapUI open source version, you'll find workarounds.  There are other tools to consider, Postman for one.  Postman seems to be gaining in popularity, I've not used it much, but if you look for Danny Dainton on Git Hub, he has an amazing repo for Postman resources.